# Query Select Option PHP

Tags: php, query, value

Como fazer uma query com select option que o utilizador possa escolher?

No frontend:

```
<form method="post" action="Procurarquery.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span class="LABEL4CSS" id="LABEL4">Estado</span>
    <select name="estado" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOFABCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
        <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
        <option value="Autorizado">Autorizado</option>
        <option value="Condicionado">Condicionado</option>
        <option value="Não Autorizado">Não Autorizado</option>
    </select>
```

No backend:

```
 if (isset($_POST['estado'])) {
     switch($_POST['estado']) {
             case 'Indiferente':
                 $sql = "QUERYYYYYY";
                 $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                 break;
             case 'Autorizado':
                 $sql = "Query Autorizado";
                 $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
             break;
```

Agora tenho uma duvida. Se eu quiser colocar outro ($_POST['Mes'])
Como posso fazer para selecionar o ESTADO e o MES ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Depende de como você está a gravar os dados na base de dados. Tudo em um único campo, separado...?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você deseja saber quantas escolhas teve cada opiton value, nãe é?

Comment: Esta pergunta está pouco clara... quer fazer uma query à base de dados (MySql por exemplo) ou usar uma query string (url)? ou nem uma nem outra?

Comment: E quer fazer uma query à base de dados ou a outra página?

Comment: Quero fazer uma query a Base de dados. Para mostrar o que foi pedido nos Options value

Comment: @user3253195, Qual é a base de dados? já tem? é MySql? pode usar-se jQuery ou Mootools por exemplo ou prefere javascript simples?

Comment: Sim uma Base de dados em Mysql. Quero utilizar o mais simples para mostrar a query

Answer (score 1):

Depende muito do que é selecionável ou não, do que é obrigatório, etc.

Pelo que percebi da pergunta eu faria assim:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bd_table";

    if (isset($_POST['estado'])) {
       switch($_POST['estado']) {
          case 'Indiferente':
             $sql .= " WHERE estado = 1";
             break;
          case 'Autorizado':
             $sql .= " WHERE estado = 2";
              break;
       }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['mes'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['estado'])) 
           $sql .= " AND "; 
        else
           $sql .= " WHERE ";

        $sql .= "mes = '".$_POST['mes']."'";
    }

    $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//define a variável mes
$qmes = "";
//se estiver preenchida adiciona valor
if (isset($_POST['mes'])) {
    $qmes = " AND col_mes = '".$_POST['mes']."'"; 
}

if (isset($_POST['estado'])) {
     switch($_POST['estado']) {
             case 'Indiferente':
                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bd_table WHERE col_estado = 1".$qmes;
                 break;
             case 'Autorizado':
                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bd_table WHERE col_estado = 2".$qmes;
             break;
// tira o comando de dentro do case
                 $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Se eu entendi, isto deve ajudar